# List View with dynamic separators-Database

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

I want to make a simple application in which I have a database in this format.

**Category**
     item 1
     item 2
     item n

**Category 2**
item1 item n

I want to load all this data in a List View with categories as separators with buttons on them
and all the items beneath them just as a typical Contact App with Alphabets separator(But with button on every separator). Needs :

1. Databse can have infinite cateogories
2. database can have infinite items in one category 
   [image]
   So how to load all this thing in a List view? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: for better performance do not load all items ... maybe you can use [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) edit: `Databse can have infinite cateogories` < can't be true :)

Comment: can you elaborate more ? Whats the best way to deal with this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something that will help you, I have done something like that in my application.

First create some xml to hold your data
  This is my activity_main

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/listbg" 
    >
</ExpandableListView>
```

Xml 2; listrow_details

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" >
</TextView>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black" />
```

Xml 3 : listview_group

```
        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
android:gravity="left"
android:paddingLeft="32dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:text="Test"
android:textSize="14sp"
android:textAlignment="textEnd"
android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Create a group class:

```
 public class Group {

  public String string;
  public final List<String> children = new ArrayList<String>();

  public Group(String string) {
    this.string = string;
  }

}
```

A adapter class for your expandable list view:

```
     public class MyExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

  private final SparseArray<Group> groups;
  public LayoutInflater inflater;
  public Activity activity;

  public MyExpandableListAdapter(Activity act, SparseArray<Group> groups) {
    activity = act;
    this.groups = groups;
    inflater = act.getLayoutInflater();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).children.get(childPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
      boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final String children = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    TextView text = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow_details, null);
    }
    text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    text.setText(children);
    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, children,
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition).children.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return groups.get(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public int getGroupCount() {
    return groups.size();
  }

  @Override
  public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
  }

  @Override
  public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
      View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     ExpandableListView eLV = (ExpandableListView) parent;
   eLV.expandGroup(groupPosition);


    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_group, null);
    }
    Group group = (Group) getGroup(groupPosition);
    ((TextView) convertView).setText(group.string);
//    ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);
    return convertView;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

and finally do this in your main activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  // More efficient than HashMap for mapping integers to objects
  SparseArray<Group> groups = new SparseArray<Group>();

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    createData();
    ExpandableListView listView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setGroupIndicator(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.listbg));
    MyExpandableListAdapter adapter = new MyExpandableListAdapter(this,
        groups);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
  }

  public void createData() {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
      Group group = new Group("Test " + j);
      for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        group.children.add("Sub Item" + i);
      }
      groups.append(j, group);
    }
  }

  }
```

Above code will solve your problem, I have used a drawable xml to customize look for my expendablelistview

here it is listbg.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
<item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
<item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />
 </selector>
```

You can use buttons or anything to customize according to your needs.
This code will solve your problem i suppose, PEACE:)

**Screenshot**

[image: This is how it will look like]

Comment: can you post some screen shots of what it actually looks like ?

Comment: thats good . can you please see my question again , cause i need a button on that header of ListView so that I can give some functionality of editing deleting the List item on that boy ! all i know is that there is an expand button on that header, can we Over ride it to do some other task ?

Comment: insert a button in group.xml and call that button in your adapter class, set functionality on its onClick. You can get group id from GetGroupView function, Get the id of group and do whatever yo want with that group.  simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So i found something useful [here](http://www.androidguys.com/2009/12/21/dev-tools-customizing-expandablelistview/) and thats what i am looking for 
So the Answer is :

1. Use Expandable List View
2. Hide the Expand button
3. make it custom(above link is helpful in that case).
   @cyberwalker thanks for help